# Python C extension link with a custom shared library

Tags: python, shared-libraries, zlib, cython

I am writing a Python C extension on a very old Red Hat system.  The system has zlib 1.2.3, which does not correctly support large files.  Unfortunately, I can't just upgrade the system zlib to a newer version, since some of the packages poke into internal zlib structures and that breaks on newer zlib versions.

I would like to build my extension so that all the zlib calls (`gzopen()`, `gzseek()` etc.) are resolved to a custom zlib that I install in my user directory, without affecting the rest of the Python executable and other extensions.

I have tried statically linking in `libz.a` by adding `libz.a` to the gcc command line during linking, but it did not work (still cannot create large files using `gzopen()` for example).  I also tried passing `-z origin -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/zlib -lz` to gcc, but that also did not work.

Since newer versions of zlib are still named `zlib 1.x`, the `soname` is the same, so I *think* symbol versioning would not work.  Is there a way to do what I want to do?

I am on a 32-bit Linux system.  Python version is 2.6, which is custom-built.

*Edit*:

I created a minimal example.  I am using Cython (version 0.19.1).

File `gztest.pyx`:

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf, fprintf, stderr
from libc.string cimport strerror
from libc.errno cimport errno
from libc.stdint cimport int64_t

cdef extern from "zlib.h":
    ctypedef void *gzFile
    ctypedef int64_t z_off_t

    int gzclose(gzFile fp)
    gzFile gzopen(char *path, char *mode)
    int gzread(gzFile fp, void *buf, unsigned int n)
    char *gzerror(gzFile fp, int *errnum)

cdef void print_error(void *gzfp):
    cdef int errnum = 0
    cdef const char *s = gzerror(gzfp, &errnum)
    fprintf(stderr, "error (%d): %s (%d: %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno), errnum, s)

cdef class GzFile:
    cdef gzFile fp
    cdef char *path
    def __init__(self, path, mode='rb'):
        self.path = path
        self.fp = gzopen(path, mode)
        if self.fp == NULL:
            raise IOError('%s: %s' % (path, strerror(errno)))

    cdef int read(self, void *buf, unsigned int n):
        cdef int r = gzread(self.fp, buf, n)
        if r <= 0:
            print_error(self.fp)
        return r

    cdef int close(self):
        cdef int r = gzclose(self.fp)
        return 0

def read_test():
    cdef GzFile ifp = GzFile('foo.gz')
    cdef char buf[8192]
    cdef int i, j
    cdef int n
    errno = 0
    for 0 <= i < 0x200:
        for 0 <= j < 0x210:
            n = ifp.read(buf, sizeof(buf))
            if n <= 0:
                break

        if n <= 0:
            break

        printf('%lld\n', <long long>ifp.tell())

    printf('%lld\n', <long long>ifp.tell())
    ifp.close()
```

File `setup.py`:

```
import sys
import os

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'CUSTOM_GZ' in os.environ:
        d = {
            'include_dirs': ['/home/alok/zlib_lfs/include'],
            'extra_objects': ['/home/alok/zlib_lfs/lib/libz.a'],
            'extra_compile_args': ['-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g3 -ggdb']
        }
    else:
        d = {'libraries': ['z']}
    ext = Extension('gztest', sources=['gztest.pyx'], **d)
    setup(name='gztest', cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext}, ext_modules=[ext])
```

My custom `zlib` is in `/home/alok/zlib_lfs` (zlib version 1.2.8):

```
$ ls ~/zlib_lfs/lib/
libz.a  libz.so  libz.so.1  libz.so.1.2.8  pkgconfig
```

To compile the module using this `libz.a`:

```
$ CUSTOM_GZ=1 python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning gztest.pyx to gztest.c
building 'gztest' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/alok/zlib_lfs/include -I/opt/include/python2.6 -c gztest.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/gztest.o -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g3 -ggdb
gcc -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/gztest.o /home/alok/zlib_lfs/lib/libz.a -L/opt/lib -lpython2.6 -o /home/alok/gztest.so
```

`gcc` is being passed all the flags I want (adding full path to `libz.a`, large file flags, etc.).

To build the extension without my custom zlib, I can compile without `CUSTOM_GZ` defined:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning gztest.pyx to gztest.c
building 'gztest' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/include/python2.6 -c gztest.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/gztest.o
gcc -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/gztest.o -L/opt/lib -lz -lpython2.6 -o /home/alok/gztest.so
```

We can check the size of the `gztest.so` files:

```
$ stat --format='%s %n' original/gztest.so custom/gztest.so 
62398 original/gztest.so
627744 custom/gztest.so
```

So, the statically linked file is much larger, as expected.

I can now do:

```
>>> import gztest
>>> gztest.read_test()
```

and it will try to read `foo.gz` in the current directory.

When I do that using non-statically linked `gztest.so`, it works as expected until it tries to read more than 2 GB.

When I do that using statically linked `gztest.so`, it dumps core:

```
$ python -c 'import gztest; gztest.read_test()'
error (2): No such file or directory (0: )
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The error about `No such file or directory` is misleading -- the file exists and is `gzopen()` actually returns successfully.  `gzread()` fails though.

Here is the `gdb` backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf730eae4 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0xf70725e2 in ?? () from /lib/libz.so.1
#2  0xf6ce9c70 in __pyx_f_6gztest_6GzFile_close (__pyx_v_self=0xf6f75278) at gztest.c:1140
#3  0xf6cea289 in __pyx_pf_6gztest_2read_test (__pyx_self=<optimized out>) at gztest.c:1526
#4  __pyx_pw_6gztest_3read_test (__pyx_self=0x0, unused=0x0) at gztest.c:1379
#5  0xf769910d in call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3690
#6  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0x8115c64, throwflag=0) at Python/ceval.c:2389
#7  0xf769a3b4 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0xf6faada0, globals=0xf6ff81c4, locals=0xf6ff81c4, args=0x0, argcount=0, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:2968
#8  0xf769a433 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=0xf6faada0, globals=0xf6ff81c4, locals=0xf6ff81c4) at Python/ceval.c:522
#9  0xf76bbe1a in run_mod (arena=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, filename=<optimized out>, mod=<optimized out>) at Python/pythonrun.c:1335
#10 PyRun_StringFlags (str=0x80a24c0 "import gztest; gztest.read_test()\n", start=257, globals=0xf6ff81c4, locals=0xf6ff81c4, flags=0xffbf2888) at Python/pythonrun.c:1298
#11 0xf76bd003 in PyRun_SimpleStringFlags (command=0x80a24c0 "import gztest; gztest.read_test()\n", flags=0xffbf2888) at Python/pythonrun.c:957
#12 0xf76ca1b9 in Py_Main (argc=1, argv=0xffbf2954) at Modules/main.c:548
#13 0x080485b2 in main ()
```

One of the problems seems to be that the second line in the backtrace refers to `libz.so.1`!  If I do `ldd gztest.so`, I get, among other lines:

```
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xf6f87000)
```

I am not sure why that is happening though.

*Edit 2*:

I ended up doing the following:

- compiled my custom zlib with all the symbols exported with a `z_` prefix.  `zlib`'s `configure` script makes this very easy: just run `./configure --zprefix ...`.
- called `gzopen64()` instead of `gzopen()` in my Cython code.  This is because I wanted to make sure I am using the correct "underlying" symbol.
- used `z_off64_t` explicitly.
- statically link my custom `zlib.a` into the shared library generated by Cython.  I used `'-Wl,--whole-archive /home/alok/zlib_lfs_z/lib/libz.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive'` while linking with gcc to achieve that.  There might be other ways or this might not be needed but it seemed the simplest way to make sure the correct library gets used.

With the above changes, large files work while the rest of the Python extension modules/processes work as before.

Comment: What packages prevent upgrading zlib?  The only one I am aware of is libxml, which has been fixed.

Comment: @MarkAdler: yes, it's libxml.  The problem is that it's a very old system so the version of libxml on the system has that bug.  Upgrading libxml from 2.6.26 (the version installed) to 2.7.7 is something I would like to avoid since libxml gets used in so many other places and I am not sure if it won't break anything else.

Comment: Static linking to a custom `libz.a` ought to work, assuming the bug is definately in libz, and you've compiled a version without the bug. Are you sure you're picking up the right version? Try renaming it to `libmyz.a` and using `-lmyz`.

Comment: Oh, and if you're using zlib via Python's `zlibmodule.c`, rather than calling it directly, there's a [bug in that](http://bugs.python.org/issue8651) which looks like it wasn't fixed until Python 2.7.

Comment: @Aya, I will try again tonight and post an update soon.  I am not using `zlibmodule.c`.

Comment: @Alok TBH, after re-reading the question, it doesn't sound like that's the issue - specifying the correct `libz.a` (rather than using a `-l` param) on the link line should've worked. It might help to include a bit more info, like: which version of zlib you're using, where you got it from, the code you're using to extend Python, and an example of a failing case, so people can attempt to reproduce the fault.

Comment: @Aya, I added some code and details on how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is similar to the problem in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232822/linking-with-multiple-versions-of-a-library), except I get the opposite behavior.

I downloaded a tarball of `zlib-1.2.8`, ran `./configure`, then changed the following `Makefile` variables...

```
CFLAGS=-O3  -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

SFLAGS=-O3  -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

...mostly to add the `-fPIC` to `libz.a` so I could link to it in a shared library.

I then added some `printf()` statements in the `gzlib.c` functions `gzopen()`, `gzopen64()`, and `gz_open()` so I could easily tell if these were being called.

After building `libz.a` and `libz.so`, I created a really simple `foo.c`...

```
#include "zlib-1.2.8/zlib.h"

void main()
{
    gzFile foo = gzopen("foo.gz", "rb");
}
```

...and compiled both a `foo` standalone binary, and a `foo.so` shared library with...

```
gcc -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o zlib-1.2.8/libz.a
gcc -shared -o foo.so foo.o zlib-1.2.8/libz.a
```

Running `foo` worked as expected, and printed...

```
gzopen64
gz_open
```

...but using the `foo.so` in Python with...

```
import ctypes

foo = ctypes.CDLL('./foo.so')
foo.main()
```

...didn't print anything, so I guess it's using Python's `libz.so`...

```
$ ldd `which python`
        ...
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5af2c68000)
        ...
```

...even though `foo.so` doesn't use it...

```
$ ldd foo.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff93600000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc8bfa98000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc8c0078000)
```

The only way I could get it to work was to open the custom `libz.so` directly with...

```
import ctypes

libz = ctypes.CDLL('zlib-1.2.8/libz.so.1.2.8')
libz.gzopen64('foo.gz', 'rb')
```

...which printed out...

```
gzopen64
gz_open
```

Note that the translation from `gzopen` to `gzopen64` is done by the pre-processor, so I had to call `gzopen64()` directly.

So that's one way to fix it, but a better way would probably be to recompile your custom Python 2.6 to either link to the static `zlib-1.2.8/libz.a`, or disable `zlibmodule.c` completely, then you'll have more flexibility in your linking options.

---

**Update**

Regarding `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` vs. `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`: I only pointed that out because of this comment in `zlib.h`...

```
/* provide 64-bit offset functions if _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE defined, and/or
 * change the regular functions to 64 bits if _FILE_OFFSET_BITS is 64 (if
 * both are true, the application gets the *64 functions, and the regular
 * functions are changed to 64 bits) -- in case these are set on systems
 * without large file support, _LFS64_LARGEFILE must also be true
 */
```

...the implication being that the `gzopen64()` function won't be exposed if you don't define `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`. I'm not sure if `_LFS64_LARGEFILE` applies to your system or not.

Comment: Hmm, this gives me some ideas -- I am off to running some experiments along the lines of what you did with my Cython code now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alok I figured it'd be easier to do it with `ctypes`, but if you still want to use a Cython wrapper, then it ought to work if you `dlopen()` the `libz.so.1.2.8` in the Cython code. I also noticed what looks like a typo in your `'extra_compile_args': ['-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE ...` which might need to be `-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`.

Comment: the problem is that it's some code that I am maintaining, and that code is in Cython.  About `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`, I used the flags from the output of `getconf LFS_CFLAGS`, so it wasn't a typo.  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-g_t_005fLARGEFILE64_005fSOURCE-48 says: "It is a transition interface for the period when 64 bit offsets are not generally used (see `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`)", so I think I don't need to define `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`, but I will try with that anyway.

Comment: Somehow @Aya is getting eaten up.  Weird.

Comment: @Alok I can't parse that last comment.

Comment: my comment about `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` started with "@Aya" (so does this comment), but for some reason, StackOverflow is not showing the "@Aya" at the beginning of the coment.  My second comment was commenting on that fact.

Comment: @Alok Ahh. Yeah. I think it's because it's redundant to use the @ for the author of a post, since they always get notified, although you can use it if another user has commented on the post, in order to disambiguate whose comment you're referring to.

Comment: @Alok See update regarding `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` vs. `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`.

Comment: OK, I just tried with `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` in addition to the other flags.  Also tried using `gzopen64()` directly.  Still no go (same result as in my post).  I am trying ctypes/dlopen now.  Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31420/discussion-between-alok-and-aya)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ctypes.html). Write your C library as a normal shared library and than use `ctypes` to access it. You would need to write a bit more Python code to transfer the data from Python data structures into C ones. The big advantage is that you can isolate everything from the rest of the system. You can explicitly specify the `*.so` file you would like to load. The Python C API is not needed. I have quite good experiences with `ctypes`. This should be not too difficult for you since you seem proficient with C.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the answer.  I didn't try ctypes, but I actually did try using `dlopen()` and loading the symbols explicitly from the full path of the new shared library.  I would have thought that this approach would have worked too, but I kept getting either `gzopen64` symbol being not defined, or segmentation fault.  I am going to update my post with more details soon.  (I am actually writing this extension in Cython.)